# Use div elements in Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a div which has different values defined

```
<div class="scontent" scountry="en-GB" snumber="22000"></div>
```

In addition I have an external Javascript file which should use the data provided in the div above and output the info.

```
<script>document.write("22000en-GB"); </script>
```

Is it possible with plain Javascript to look for the div with class="scontent" and include the values of scountry and snumber into the Javascript code dynamically?

Comment: will you elaborate more what exactly you want to mean by writing code into javascript code.
If you want to access other value in javascript you can use like this
`document.getElementsByClassName("scontent")[0].dataset. scountry`

Answer (score 2):

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('scontent')[0];
let scountry = element.getAttribute('scountry');
let snumber = element.getAttribute('snumber');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all additional attributes inside `dataset` of any element

```
const ele = document.getElementsByClassName("scontent")[0].dataset;
const scountry = ele.scountry;
const snumber = ele.snumber;
```